# Как вернуть цвет фигуры в Python?

Tags: python, графика, tkinter, цвета, python-3.x

Есть ли какой-нибудь способ вернуть значение цвета фигуры в Python?Нужно составить условие,является ли нужная фигура требуемого цвета?Используется библиотека tkinter.

И еще небольшой вопросик отдельно.Есть какие-нибудь другие библиотеки,где есть возможность отрисовать графические примитивы?Может что-то интересней и с более большим функционалом.

Comment: @Семён Сигунава, постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т.д. 
Понятие фигура довольно расплывчата. 

По второму вопросу - PyQt.

Comment: @Alex Krass,извиняюсь.Тогда,собственно суть.Имеется фигура.Квадрат.С заданным значением цвета заливки.Есть ли в tkinter что-то,что поможет мне вернуть значение цвета функции.Если на словах:"является ли этот квадрат красным?".

Comment: Так квадрат - это что-то уже отрисованное на экране (т.е. надо просто определить цвет определенной нарисованной на экране области)? Или это какой-то объект, который предстоит отрисовать?

Comment: @BOPOH,не совсем.Квадрат в моём случае это объект,который создается методом create_rectangle,среди аргументов которого есть цвет заливки fill.Вопрос в том,как вернуть значение fill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Извиняюсь, не сразу заметил, что речь идет о примитивах и я так пониманию используется canvas? Да, можно получить цветовое значение уже созданных примитивов и изменять их. Есть функция

```
canvas.itemconfigure(tagOrId, option, ...)
```

Посмотрите тут главу 8 и в частности 8.6 как список доступных функций: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html

Как короткий пример:

```
rect = canvas.create_rectangle(10,10,290,290, fill="blue")
options = canvas.itemconfig(rect)
print (options["fill"][4])
```

Comment: @Alex Krass,спасибо за ссылку.Нашел более подходящий метод .itemcget(tagorid,option).Возвращает цвет моих фигур.